# C struct Inheritance vs C++ POD struct Inheritance

Tags: c++, c, inheritance, struct

Suppose I use the fairly common idiom to define struct inheritance in `my_header.h`:

```
struct A { int a_field; ... };
struct B { struct A _as_A; int b_field; ... };
```

Now in my C code I can do `binstance._as_A.a_field`, or I can cast a pointer to B to a pointer to A, and so forth.

My question is this. Suppose that I now define a new C++ header `my_header.hpp`:

```
struct A { int a_field; ... }
struct B : A { int b_field; ... }
```

Suppose I do this taking care to make sure ***B is a POD type***.

Am I guaranteed that the memory layout of a B instance is the same in C and C++?

Comment: (the reason why I'm interested in this is that it would allow me to use `b.a_field` in C++, which would be more readable, while still exporting a C interface, which is a possibility I want to preserve)

Comment: You can not export structs with inheritance as a part of C interface.

Comment: But `B` cannot be a pod type, its members must exist in exactly one class

Comment: Base classes are not guaranteed to be at the beginning of the object.

Comment: @BoPersson this is a pre-C++11 answer, C++11 changes it completely. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType

Comment: @n.m.- Allowing public base classes in an aggregate seems to be a C++17 change that I haven't noticed, but ok.

Comment: *the reason why I'm interested in this is that it would allow me to use b.a_field in C++, which would be more readable*  You would have two separate header files that try to define the same object.  I don't see how that is "more readable".  Also, untrackable dependencies like this are an O&M nightmare.  "I changed this C header file, and now that C++ application over there is broken?!?!"

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose I do this taking care to make sure B is a POD type.

As pointed out in the comments, `B` will never be a POD type, because it will never be a standard-layout class.

> 7 A *standard-layout class* is a class that:
>
> [...]
>
> (7.5) -- either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
>
> [...]
>
> 10 A *POD struct*<sup>110</sup> is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). Similarly, a *POD union* is a union that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). A *POD class* is a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

Because of that, the literal question you asked turns out irrelevant: even if the layout order were guaranteed, you still wouldn't be allowed to do what you're trying to do. This matters because concrete implementations do typically define the layout order the way you're hoping, as part of the ABI, but that's not enough for what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

No. The C++ standard draft N4296 states:

> **10 Derived classes**
>   <sup>5</sup> The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object (1.8) is unspecified. [...]
>   <sup>8</sup>
>    [ Note: A base class subobject might have a layout (3.7) different from the layout of a most derived object
>   of the same type. [...] ]

Comment: I believe this refers to multiple inheritance

Comment: Yes, I assumed there would be more than one base `struct` used this way.

Comment: @PasserBy I just added a bit that should also cover the single base class case.

Comment: 8 is only Note and therefore not normative. I wonder what is the rule that causes it. I also wonder how a base subobject of different layout would work, considering you can implicitly convert from derived pointer to base class pointer, and that pointer can be passed to a function that doesn't necessarily know whether the pointer is to a most derived object, or to a base subobject.

Comment: @user2079303 I think it's actually "not allowed because there is no explicit rule that allows it", and the non-normative note gives a hint at that.

Comment: @alain ah, a note about lack of rule makes sense. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Actually I only meant to use this for single inheritance.